# Magento - conditional block in right column

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

how can I make a conditional block like the right callout of the dog, in the right column of magento ?

I have tried this code my in my right_col.phtml, but it don't works.

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo MageMage::getBaseUrl ('skin'); ?>images/button_suscribe.png">
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is "right callout of the dog"? And I don't see any conditionals in your example. Explain the question better, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it in ../template/callouts/right_col.phtml but it's not clear to me in which condition do you want to display this.

Comment: The condition is: if user is logged in

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())